# Let $|x| := \sqrt{|x|_1^2 + |x|_2^2}$. Is $\| \cdot \|$ related to $\| \cdot \|_1$ and $\| \cdot \|_2$?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

In solving [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4402888/construct-an-equivalent-and-strictly-convex-norm-on-a-separable-banach-space-who) exercise, I come across below question.

> Let $(E, | \cdot |_1)$ be a normed space and $(E', \| \cdot \|_1)$ its dual space. Let $|\cdot|_2$ be another norm on $E$ and $\|\cdot\|_2$ its dual norm on $E'$. We define a new norm $| \cdot|$ on $E$ by $|x| := \sqrt{|x|_1^2 + |x|_2^2}$. Let $\| \cdot \|$ be the dual norm of $|\cdot|$.

Is there any relation between $\| \cdot \|$ and $\| \cdot \|_1, \| \cdot \|_2$?

Comment: Do you assume that the norms $|\cdot |_1$ and $|\cdot |_1$ are equivalent ? If not the dual space of $E$ depends on the norm on $E.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc you're right. I also assume that they're equivalent.

Comment: @Akira As $|x|\ge \max(|x|_1,|x|_2)$ then $\max(\|\cdot \|_1 ,\|\cdot \|_2)\ge \|\cdot \|.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is inspired by the formula in the title of [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4403830/if-x-sqrtx-12-x-22-on-e-then-f-2-min-g-in-e-lef/4403832#4403832).
Let $f,g\in E'.$ For $0\neq x\in E$ we have
$$|f(x)| \le |f(x)-g(x)|+|g(x)|=|x|_1{|f(x)-g(x)|\over |x|_1}+|x|_2 {|g(x)|\over |x|_2}\\
\le |x|_1\,|f-g\|_1+|x|_2\,\|g\|_2\le \sqrt{|x|_1^2+|x|_2^2}\,\,\sqrt{\|f-g\|_1^2+\|g\|_2^2}\\ =|x|\, \sqrt{\|f-g\|_1^2+\|g\|_2^2}
$$
Hence
$\|f\|\le \sqrt{\|f-g\|_1^2+\|g\|_2^2}$  $\ $ for any $g\in E'.$ Therefore
\begin{equation}\|f\|\le \inf_{g\in E'}\sqrt{\|f-g\|_1^2+\|g\|_2^2}
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you so much for your elaborate answer!

Comment: My recent [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4403830/if-x-sqrtx-12-x-22-on-e-then-f-2-min-g-in-e-lef/4403832#4403832) may be of your interest :v

Comment: @Analyst It seems you have much better result  than mine, as you have calculated the norm precisely.