# The space $(E, |\cdot|)$ is strictly convex if and only if the map $\varphi(x) := |x|^{2}$ is strictly convex

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, normed-spaces

I'm doing Ex 1.26 in Brezis's book of Functional Analysis.

> Let $(E, |\cdot|)$ be an n.v.s.
>
> - One says that $|\cdot|$ is strictly convex (or that the space $E$ is strictly convex) if $|t x+(1-t) y|<1$ for all $x, y \in E$ with $x \neq y,|x|=|y|=1$ and for all $t \in(0,1)$.
> - One says that a map $\varphi: E \to (-\infty, +\infty]$ is strictly convex if $\varphi(t x+(1-t) y)<t \varphi(x)+(1-t) \varphi(y)$ for all $x, y \in E$ with $x \neq y$ and for all $t \in(0,1)$.
>
> Then the norm $|\cdot|$ is strictly convex if and only if the map $\varphi(x) := |x|^{2}$ is strictly convex.

Could you have a check on my attempt?

I post my proof separately as an answer below. This allows me to subsequently remove this question from unanswered list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We fix $t \in(0,1)$ and $x, y \in E$.

- Assume that $\varphi$ is strictly convex.

Let $x \neq y,|x|=|y|=1$. Then $$
|t x+(1-t) y|^2  = \varphi(tx + (1-t)y < t\varphi(x) + (1-t) \varphi(y) =  t|x|^2 + (1-t)|y|^2 = 1.
$$
Hence $|t x+(1-t) y| < 1$.

- Assume that $E$ is strictly convex.

Let $x \neq y, x' := x/|x|$, and $y' := y/|y|$. Then $|x'|=|y'|=1$. Let $t' := t|x|/(t|x|+(1-t)|y|)$. Then
$$
\left |\frac{t x+(1-t) y}{t|x|+(1-t)|y|} \right |^2 = \left | \frac{t|x| x'+(1-t) |y| y'}{t|x|+(1-t)|y|} \right |^2 =  |t'x' + (1-t')y'|^2 < 1.
$$

It follows that $|t x+(1-t) y|^2 < (t|x|+(1-t)|y|)^2$. Because $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R, x \mapsto x^2$ is strongly (and thus strictly) convex, we get $(t|x|+(1-t)|y|)^2 < t|x|^2 + (1-t)|y|^2$. This completes the proof.

Comment: +1 I think Your proof is fine! Of course you should say "Let $x\neq y$ and $x,y\neq 0$" or something like that before dividing through the norms

Comment: Actually that part needs an extra treatment: Assume wlog $x=0$ then for $y\neq 0$ one has $|(1-t)y|^2=(1-t)^2|y|^2<(1-t)|y|^2$ because $(1-t)^2<1-t$ for all $t\in (0,1)$.